# How to use Python3 on the VScode terminal?

Tags: visual-studio-code, python-3.7

Is there a way to force VS Code to use only python3? It always defaults to python2.7 no matter what I try. I've tried selecting the correct interpreter as python3.7. When I open up terminal, it immediately uses python2.7, In the settings it is pointing at 3.7, but the built in terminal which is nice, always defaults to 2.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, understand that the [integrated terminal of VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal), by default, uses the same environment as the Terminal app on Mac.

> The shell used defaults to `$SHELL` on Linux and macOS, PowerShell on
>   Windows 10 and `cmd.exe` on earlier versions of Windows. These can be
>   overridden manually by setting `terminal.integrated.shell.*` in user
>   [settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings).

[image]

The default `$SHELL` on Mac is `/bin/bash` which uses `python` for Python2.7. So VS Code will just use the same `python` to mean Python2.7. When you open a bash shell, it will load your `~/.bash_profile` to apply custom aliases and other configurations you added into it.

One solution to your problem is edit your `~/.bash_profile` to alias `python` to `python3`. But I **do not recommend** this because this affects all your bash sessions, even those outside of VS Code. This can lead to nasty side effects when you run scripts that need `python` to be the system Python2.7.

You can instead configure VSCode to load its own aliases, for its own integrated terminal. First, create a file named *vscode.bash_profile* in your home directory:

```
$ cat ~/vscode.bash_profile
alias python=$(which python3)
```

On my env, `python3` is Python3.7. You can set it to the what's applicable on your env (ex. maybe `python3.7`). Then, in VS Code, look for the Terminal shell args setting:

[image]

and then open your settings.json and add these lines:

```
"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.osx": [
    "--init-file",
    "~/vscode.bash_profile",
]
```

Finally, **restart VS Code**. The next time you open the VS Code terminal, `python` should now be using your Python 3 installation. This should not affect your bash session outside of VS Code.

Note that, if you have some custom settings from the default `~/.bash_profile`, you may want to copy it over to your `~/vscode.bash_profile`, so that you can still use it on VS Code (ex. changes to `PATH`, git-completion scripts..).

Comment: Worked for me. Make sure you don't have a -l option already in there.

Comment: This explanation is too complex for a novice. Could someone please post another answer showing exactly what and where a linux user is supposed to click on, etc.?